# Confusion in reduced residue systems

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences, reduced-residue-system

1 and 5 constitue a reduced residue system (mod 6).

The book says a set of integers $a_1,...,a_h$ is a reduced residue system if it's incongruent (mod m) and relatively prime to m, such that if a is any integer prime to m, there is an index i, $1 \leq i \leq h$, for which $a \equiv a_i(mod$ $ m)$.

1 and 5 are incongruent to (mod 6). Each one is relatively prime to 6. But what bothers me is that for some integers a, the options won't satisfy $a \equiv a_i(mod$ $ m)$.

Comment: As long as $a$ is co-prime (relatively prime) to 6, then $a\equiv a_i\mbox{ (mod m)}$

Comment: ohhhh prime to m. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Community wiki answer so the question can be marked as answered:

As discussed in the comments, the premise that $a$ is prime to $m$ is essential, and indeed any integer $a$ prime to $m$ either $a\equiv1\bmod6$ or $a\equiv5\bmod6$.